# Uniformly charged conductor in electrostatics

Tags: electrostatics, conductors

Why can we deal with uniformly charged conductors in electrostatics. The charges are on the surface. If we assume the conductor to be positively charged,then every positive charge will repel other positive charges. So,the charges won't be in equilibrium and won't that cause current to flow? I know i am wrong but i want to know which part i made a mistake. Kindly clear my doubt.

Comment: The charges arrange themselves so that the net force on each is zero, meaning no currents. Of course, when the charges are placed on the sphere initially, they will move away from each other due to repulsive forces, and there will be associated currents. There are no currents once the system reaches equilibrium.

Comment: *Why can we deal with uniformly charged conductors?* In general, the surface charge density won’t be uniform. It’s only uniform for symmetric shapes like spheres and infinite cylinders. [Here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/732255) is an example of a highly non-uniform distribution.

Answer (score 1):

In electrostatics, a conductor is an idealized medium for which a current will flow for any electric field (like idealized fluid will always flow under shear). Under these circumstances, charge can only come to equilibrium on the conductor when there is no field in the conductor and the field just outside the surface is perpendicular to the surface. Given any particular geometry for a conductor, net charge on the conductor, and external "fixed" charges in space, the problem of electrostatics is to find the charge distribution for which the E field in the conductor does exactly that. This is what is needed for no possible current flow. It is demonstrated in basically every electrodynamics book in the electrostatics chapter (generally chapter 1 or 2) that this requires the excess charge to be on the surface only (a surface density, not body density).

Your question is not really precise, but assuming what you mean is we put excess charge on a conductor and have all other charges far away, the equilibrium arrangement will be all the excess charge arranged as a surface density so that the field interior to that surface cancels. The charge *is* being repelled, but it is being repelled *perpendicularly away* from the surface of the conductor. It is taken as a given in classical electrostatics that there are materials called "conductors" which will "hold onto the charge" (not let it escape at the surface) but always allow it to move *within itself* (current in its body).

That is what the solution equations for surface charge density show in electrostatics. In the real world, charge *can* escape sometimes. That is what sparks and thermionic emission are, after all. But, mathematically, the electrostatic solution *is* the solution for which the total net charge is as given and the E field is perpendicular to the conductor surface *outside the surface* and zero *everywhere inside the surface* which are the requirements for no current to flow in the conductor.

It is worth noting that for any surface completely enclosing the conductor (and nothing else), Gauss' law will hold for the total net charge on the conductor. It is also worth noting that *dielectrics* will not come to this sort of electrostatic distribution, since in that case the charge does not flow. Dielectrics in general can have E fields inside the the 3 dimensional space of their bodies.